# What is the best way to make use of native code in nodejs?

Tags: c++, node.js, sockets, tcp, electron

I'm developing an application using nodejs/electron which has to manipulate a huge amount of data, and have written the performance-critical part of it in c++. Now that the most parts of the application are done, I'm still not sure of the best way to call the c++ code. It seems that the most natural way is to compile it as a shared library and then call it from nodejs, but for me that process seems to be so complicated, so I thought about making the c++ code a standalone executable listening on a port number, and then sending tcp requests to it from my nodejs app.

The question is then: Would that affect performance? And is that a bad design choice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

1. Put your code into it's own app and workout a way to pass in what you want it to process (via cmdline arguments, file, stdio, networking, etc...) and then run it from node.js via the child_process module.
2. Put your code into a nodejs add-on, using the [add-on SDK](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) so you can directly call it from within nodejs.
3. Compile your code to [web-assembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly) and load/run that web assembly directly from within nodejs.  If you haven't heard of web assembly before, it's a fairly new capability in Javascript engines.  A language like Rust or C or C++ compiles their code to a web assembly target. It's kind of like a low-level, generic (non-CPU-specific) assembly language that Javascript engines can directly run and other typed languages such as Rust, C or C++ can compile to directly just like they would compile to native machine language for a particular compiler target.  The JS engine then take that web assembly and compiles it on the fly to the local machine language while adding a few memory access safeguards.

> so I thought about making the c++ code a standalone executable listening on a port number, and then sending tcp requests to it from my nodejs app.

That would work just fine.

> The question is then: Would that affect performance? And is that a bad design choice?

It's kind of hard to know what your performance target is.  You probably wouldn't want some operation that you call thousands of times in rapid fashion to be in a separate server, but if you're calling it less often than that, then it could be just fine.

The nodejs add-on SDK allows you a fairly high bandwidth interface to Javascript as it's the same way that a lot of the nodejs built-in libraries are implemented.  It is more work to learn how it works because if you're going to play in-process within node.js and play with garbage collection, you have to do a lot of things a certain way (particularly anything that deals with memory or passing data to/from Javascript).  But, it's ultimately the tightest connection to your nodejs Javascript.